# Why is a skew symmetric matrix called thus?

Tags: matrices, statistics

The symmetric matrix is a lot like the symmetric curve having skewness 0 in a statistical distribution. Can we somehow relate a skew symmetric matrix with this definition to see why it is called thus?

Comment: A skew-symmetric matrix is just called "skew-symmetric" in contrast to "symmetric", see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix). Here "skew" means "anti", so not $A^T=A$, but $A^T=-A$. It is perhaps a bit far fetched to associate a skew-ness of a statistical distribution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a bit far fetched all right. That "skew"-"anti" relation was unknown. Thank you.